# Is there a way to leave a note to a moderator with the rude or abusive flag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive

A user used profanity in his code (a package name) visible in his attached screenshot in his otherwise ok (low quality but nothing criminal) question.

I flagged the question as *rude or abusive*, which got declined because, I am guessing, the moderator did not pay attention to the screenshot.

This could have been much easier if we were allowed to provide more information with the flag.

Comment: "*low quality but nothing criminal*" Posting a screenshot of code is "criminal", in terms of our rules and standards against such things.

Comment: Do you really know the user's gender?

Answer (score 16):

When a user just has an inappropriately named variable or package or what have you, if it's not *100% necessary* to know that information to answer the question, the suggestion is to just edit it out.

In this case, it sounds like the user's code was in a screenshot. That should be your bigger concern at first, and if they copy the code with the inappropriate language into the question, then you can edit to censor (again, if the package name is not important to the question!) the code yourself, rather than making the mods do it.

Generally, those flags are for when the whole post is rude or abusive, and cannot be fixed by editing. And for those cases... You *really* don't need an input box, usually. (If you do for some reason, then you use "In need of moderator attention", but that should be incredibly rare.)

Comment: Not to mention, I wouldn't consider profane package names to be "rude or abusive", merely a distasteful coding style.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Agreed, and the user in question may not have picked that package for its name, or have picked it very reluctantly because of the name. If it does what they want, they're likely more concerned with that in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to put it in my own answer, but I won't post it because yours offers an alternative and not just "the flag was correctly declined".

Comment: Yes, the "Rude" flag is for 'answers' like "You [slur] your question should be shot you [slur], why don't you go and [stereotypical ethnic behavior]."